# Trouble with BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex, biber

I was used to using BibTeX for my bibliographies, but was convinced to switch to BibLaTeX. I use MikTeX, so I went through the trouble of finding and creating a typesetting shortcut for Biber, and I thought I was ready to go.

With the example below, the text compiles, but the citekeys show in bold, and no bibliography prints at all.

I tried updating MikTeX (didn't help, and now I can't seem to go back to BibTeX)
I have run pdfLaTeX, Biber, pdfLaTeX, pdfLaTex, and other combinations numerous times. I Don't know what I could be doing wrong. Any insight?

I set up my file like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{BibDB.bib}

\begin{document}
text text text \cite{smith2017computer}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The citation, in the file `BibDB.bib` looks like:

```
@article{smith2017computer,
    title={Computer stuff},
    author={Smith, John Q and Doe, Jane},
    journal={Computer Scientist},
    volume={34},
    number={12},
    pages={54--63},
    year={2017},
    publisher={Workhouse}
    }
```

When I run biber with this, I get the error message:

```
Cannot find control file 'Example.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX?
```

The full `.blg` reads

```
[1] Config.pm:354> INFO - This is Biber 2.7
[2] Config.pm:357> INFO - Logfile is 'Example.blg'
[263] biber-MSWIN64:303> INFO - === 
[1951] Utils.pm:180> ERROR - Cannot find control file 'Example.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX?
[1952] Biber.pm:113> INFO - ERRORS: 1
```

I did pass that argument, so I don't know what to do or how to fix it.

Comment: Can you edit in the `.log` and `.blg` files?

Comment: I don't see a .log file. The .blg opens a "performance monitor", that I don't know anything about.

Comment: A pdfLaTeX run will _always_ generate a `.log`. If you have extensions hidden then you may struggle to identify it: turn that off! The `.logg` and the `.blg` are both text files: open them with your TeX editor (and ignore the fact that Windows is confused by the extension).

Comment: Thanks. The .blg shows `[1] Config.pm:354> INFO - This is Biber 2.7
[2] Config.pm:357> INFO - Logfile is 'Example.blg'
[263] biber-MSWIN64:303> INFO - === 
[1951] Utils.pm:180> ERROR - Cannot find control file 'Example.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX?
[1952] Biber.pm:113> INFO - ERRORS: 1`.   The important part of that, I think is the "this is Biber 2.7" part

Comment: @ Joseph Wright , I have hidden extensions turned off, and I don't see a .log file for it. I do see other .log files for my other documents. Any guesses as to where I might find the .log for this example?

Comment: @Aarow As I say, if you run pdfLaTeX it will make a `.log` provided there is not a catastrophic issue. What do you see when you actually run pdfLaTeX (and how do you run it)?

Comment: Your code works for me, try deleting all the auxiliary files (of course, keep the `.tex` and `.bib` ones) and then run again `pdflatex>biber>pdflatex>pdflatex`.

Comment: @Joseph Wright I am running pdfLaTeX in TeXworks, from a MikTeX distribution, by selecting pdfLaTeX from the typeset menu, and then pressing the green typeset button.

Comment: @CarLaTeX, I've don'e that, and It doesn't seem to change the output, which is a .pdf with the citekey printed in bold, and no bibliography.

Comment: @ Joseph Wright, I've found the `.log` file, is there a specific part that is of interest? I'ts pretty long.

Comment: The last thing before I surrender: do you have the `.bib` file in the same directory as the `.tex` one?

Comment: @CarLaTeX, yes, they're in the same directory. Is there any possibility that the problem is how I created the typesetting shortcut to Biber? I have doubts about that part.

Comment: Maybe, but I'm not an expert, I assure you that the code you've posted works perfectly!

Comment: @CarLaTeX thanks for your help. I'll keep playing with it.

Comment: @Aarow The two parts with the most info are the loading line (I have `Package: biblatex 2016/12/05 v3.7 programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)`) and the part where the `.bcf` is written (I have ``\openout4 = `test.bcf'.``) If you send me the entire log file I'll have  proper look (`joseph.wright@morningstar2.co.uk`).

Comment: After running `pdflatex` on `Example.tex`, the directory should contain a file called `Example.bcf` (which Biber will then use: i.e., in a command prompt, you'd run `biber Example.bcf`). Can you find the file `Example.bcf`?  If not, then the first problem has nothing to do with Biber.

Comment: Yes, there is a Example.bcf. I don't know what I'm looking at within it, but it exists.

Comment: If running `pdflatex` creates the `.bcf` file (and it is in the same directory as `Example.tex`), then you should open a command prompt and try to run the command `biber Example.bcf` and see if that works. (In Windows you can open such a prompt by doing something like `Shift + right-click` in relevant folder and selecting 'Open a Command Prompt here'.)

Comment: It compiles fine for me too (MiKTeX+TeXmaker). It's easy to configure TeXmaker so the bib compiler is `biber`.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I'll try TeXmaker if I can't figure it out any other way. It would be a shame to have to learn TeXmaker though, I've been very happy with Texworks alone until now.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 for help on how to correctly set up Biber with your editor. You don't have any of the 'move temporary files to another directory'/'use a build folder'... options enabled, do you? That is to say, the `.log`, `.bcf`, `.tex`, `.bib` are all in the same directory, correct?

Comment: Yes, they're all in one directory. I tried to set up biber that way already.

Comment: Can you try that in a clean directory again? Confirm that you can run LaTeX on your file without error. Check that a `.bcf` file is created in the same directory. Check that when you call Biber, it is called on the basename of your file. Report on anything that happens here.

Comment: @moewe, I have had to do a (full and complete) uninstall of MiKTeX, and I'm running TexWorks from TeXLive now. I'm also back to bibTeX, because I need to move forward with my project. I appreciate the help, thanks very much.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP removed and re-installed (another) the TeX distribution in the meantime, so that there is now no way to find out what caused the issue.